# how to make a signUp and SignIn. And user have to signin with the three credentials

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, signing

how to make a signUp and SignIn, The fields in the signup page will be email, nick name, password, and upload image..

> And user have to signin with all the three credentials i.e., email,
>   nick name and password

and after signin show that uploaded image. especially in flutter and firebase

(uploading image is not necessary)

Answer (score 0):

In the signup you will use the user id returned from firebase authentication and create a document with it in cloud firestore and upload the photo in cloud storage and save its path in the firestore document. And when you want to display this info you query the document. 
From a UX side you shouldn't do signin with three credentials and it's not possible to do with firebase.

Comment: thanks for your information, BTW i fixed my problem.